# Instant search in less command? (Similar to incsearch in VIM)

Tags: search, less

Is there a way to search, while I'm typing in `less`? Just like the vim option, `set incsearch`.

As I didn't find a proper way to do it, is there any similar tool that can do it?

Comment: Why Don't you use vim as your pager!?

Comment: @user1146332 hmm, I don't know if VIM could handle a stream directly, but seems ire_and_curses has given the right way to use vim

Comment: With '--' as command line argument vim reads from stdin (posted from mobile phone)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can do a search from the command line:

```
less -ppattern filename
```

Or, once inside `less`, use `/` followed by your pattern to do interactive searching (forwards). `n` and `N` repeat the search in the forward and reverse direction, respectively. That's the bare minimum you need to know; there are [many more commands](http://linux.die.net/man/1/less) for more complex or specific searches.

*Edit*: To respond to your updated question, there's currently no way to do immediate incremental searching with `less`. Have you considered using `view` instead (opens Vim in read-only mode, so will use your `incsearch` setting)? Vim can be made even more pager-like with the [vimpager](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1723) script.

Some additional information: There is an [open bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/less/+bug/905875) on the Ubuntu bug-tracker for incremental search support, but it doesn't look like it's going anywhere soon. Somebody has [implemented incremental support](https://github.com/matthewlmcclure/less/commits/master) on a github fork, but obviously you're going to have to compile a custom `less` to use that.

(And apart from the Ubuntu enhancement request there is currently (as of 2016-05-17) [no such enhancement request on the official `less` bugtracker](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/bugs.html#enhance).)

Comment: Sorry, but the initial question i posted wasn't clear, can you check my updated question?

Comment: +1 for recommending `view` (read-only vi) - i hate it when people use `vi` instead of `less` or `view`, and lock the file unnecessarily.

Comment: When I hit `n`, it adds n to the search pattern. Hitting enter terminates the search, after which hitting n has no effect. What to do?

Answer (score 3):

It was implemented in https://github.com/gwsw/less/commit/b09a0c452d08afe2da8c9632d4fa768d6474b371 2 months ago, and hopefully will be coming to a distro near us!

Answer (score 1):

```
less --incsearch filename
```

Added in [this commit](https://github.com/gwsw/less/commit/ae3757b5f1bd0dd27266eb555c911a7e7133407f) on January 13 2021.

Answer (score 0):

http://greenwoodsoftware.com/less/

Version 598 was released for beta testing on 7 December 2021.

I add `--incsearch` to my `LESS` environment variable:

```
export LESS='--incsearch  --ignore-case --status-column --LONG-PROMPT --RAW-CONTROL-CHARS --HILITE-UNREAD --tabs=4 --no-init --window=2 '
    # Man-db passes extra options to the pager via the `LESS` environment variable,
    # which Less interprets in the same way as command line options.
    # The setting is hard-coded at compile time and starts with -i.
    # (The value is "-ix8RmPm%s$PM%s$" as of Man-db 2.6.2; the P…$ part is the prompt string.)


    # "--RAW-CONTROL-CHARS":   Get color support for 'less'
    # --no-init: This is sometimes  desirable if the deinitialization string does something unnecessary, like clearing the screen
    # --HILITE-UNREAD:  highlight first unread line after forward movement

    # https://www.topbug.net/blog/2016/09/27/make-gnu-less-more-powerful/
source $HOME/dot_file/color_less_wf.zsh
```

> These are the differences between version 590 and version 598:

```
Add the --header option.
Add the --no-number-headers option.
Add the --status-line option.
Add the --redraw-on-quit option.
Add the --search-options option.
Add 'H' color type to set color of header lines.
Add #version conditional to lesskey.
Add += syntax to variable section in lesskey files.
Allow option name in -- command to end with '=' in addition to '\n'.
Add $HOME/.config to possible locations of lesskey file.
Add $XDG_STATE_HOME and $HOME/.local/state to possible locations of history file.
Don't read or write history file in secure mode.
Fix display of multibyte and double-width chars in prompt.
Fix ESC-BACKSPACE command when BACKSPACE key does not send 0x08.
Add more \k codes to lesskey format.
Fix bug when empty file is modified while viewing it.
Fix bug when parsing a malformed lesskey file.
Fix bug scrolling history when --incsearch is set.
Fix buffer overflow when invoking lessecho with more than 63 -m/-n options.
Fix display bugs with --header.
Fix bug restoring color at end of highlighted text.
Fix bug in parsing lesskey file.
```